# want to run my html page on local server using node when i am loading the page but the css file is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My Folder Structure.

[image]

- node_modules

- public
- form.css

- script
- view

- server.js
- package.json
- webForm.html

below is my server.js file

```
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var app= express();

var port = 8080;

app.use("/" , function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/webForm.html"));
});

app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.listen(port);
```

and below the webForm.html file where i have referenced the css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Basic Details</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/form.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Please see i am making any mistake in my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "ex-website",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: + node_modules
- public
 - form.css
+ script
+ view
server.js
package.json
webForm.html

Comment: could you provide a tree view of your folder structure

Comment: i was trying to put tree view but it changed it into list.
how can i do it @Challe

Comment: You could edit it into your post. Instead of posting it in commments.

Comment: @Challe i have added image of folder structure

Comment: That looks like it should work. Do some debugging. Look at the developer tools in the browser. Look at the network tab. Make sure the request is being made. See what the response is.

Comment: `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` — I can't think of any reason to use that legacy character encoding for new development in this century. We've had excellent support for UTF-8 for about two decades now.

Comment: i tried the meta for charset you have given but still its not working and the status code is showing OK 200 for CSS file @Quentin

Comment: Changing the character encoding to UTF-8 is just a best practice, it shouldn't have any bearing on the problem.

Comment: If the stylesheet is getting a 200 response, then the problem isn't likely to be with loading it, but with something being wrong about the CSS file itself, and you haven't shown us that.

Comment: that's a simple css file applying background color to whole body , however when i am running the cmd nodemon webForm.html i am getting an error Unexpected token '<'
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... @Quentin

Comment: earlier when i was just starting the sever with just nodemon i was able to load the page without css.
Example :-  D:\NodeJS\webForm>nodemon

Comment: `nodemon` monitors a JS program, not an HTML document. It doesn't make sense to pass it `webForm.html` as an argument.

Answer (score -1):

Did you tried the "."

`href="./assets/form.css"`

Comment: i tried status code is showing 304 Not modified in Network section of debuger

Comment: I can't see how that would make a difference. It would break the path for any URLs that are not at the root of the site. (There aren't any at the moment, but this is just less flexible than the current approach).

Answer (score -1):

This should be enough.

```
app.use('/assets', express.static('public'))
```

Comment: That makes the path relative to the current working directory and not the directory the module is in. It could break it. It won't help.

Comment: You never explained making the path relative to the current working directory is a problem for you. You should put this expectation in the question.

Comment: **I** didn't ask the question, and even if I did, it wouldn't make sense to list all the problems that I'd already solved just in case someone decided to provide an answer that introduced a new problem without solving the current one.